# I want to create two calculators place side by side with html

Tags: html, css

I am using Sublime to create two calculators side by side with html 5 but the final result are two calculators one above and the other one at the bottom.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design2.css" >
    <title>Calculator Italy</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="skyblue">
    <form>
      <div id="italyCalc">
        <input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>

        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('1')" value="1" >
        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('2')" value="2" >
        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('3')" value="3" >
        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('+')" value="+" ><br>

        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('4')" value="4" >
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('5')" value="5" >
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('6')" value="6" >
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="deleteLast()" value="<--" ><br>

        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('7')" value="7" >
        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('8')" value="8" >
        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('9')" value="9" >

        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('.')" value="." ><br>
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('0')" value="0" >
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('-')" value="-" >
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('*')" value="*" >
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('/')" value="/" ><br>

        <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="adding('C')" value="C" >
        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="power('2')" value="X^2" >
        <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="returnResult()" value="=" >

      </div>
      <div id="italyCalc2">
        <input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>

        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('1')" value="1" >
        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('2')" value="2" >
        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('3')" value="3" >
        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('+')" value="+" ><br>

        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('4')" value="4" >
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('5')" value="5" >
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('6')" value="6" >
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="deleteLast()" value="<--" ><br>

        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('7')" value="7" >
        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('8')" value="8" >
        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('9')" value="9" >

        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('.')" value="." ><br>
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('0')" value="0" >
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('-')" value="-" >
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('*')" value="*" >
        <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('/')" value="/" ><br>

        <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="adding('C')" value="C" >
        <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="power('2')" value="X^2" >
        <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="returnResult()" value="=" >

      </div>
    </form>
    <script src="logic2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In other words I want that one calculator will be placed on the left and the other one on the right, both at the same distance from the top.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try with CSS3 Flex Box

Answer (score 1):

You can simply doing it by giving both div's `float: left;` like so:

```css
#italyCalc, #italyCalc2 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <div id="italyCalc">
            <input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('1')" value="1" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('2')" value="2" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('3')" value="3" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('+')" value="+" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('4')" value="4" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('5')" value="5" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('6')" value="6" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="deleteLast()" value="<--" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('7')" value="7" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('8')" value="8" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('9')" value="9" >

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('.')" value="." ><br>
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('0')" value="0" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('-')" value="-" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('*')" value="*" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('/')" value="/" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="adding('C')" value="C" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="power('2')" value="X^2" >
            <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="returnResult()" value="=" >

        </div>
        <div id="italyCalc2">
            <input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('1')" value="1" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('2')" value="2" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('3')" value="3" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('+')" value="+" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('4')" value="4" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('5')" value="5" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('6')" value="6" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="deleteLast()" value="<--" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('7')" value="7" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('8')" value="8" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('9')" value="9" >

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('.')" value="." ><br>
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('0')" value="0" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('-')" value="-" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('*')" value="*" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('/')" value="/" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="adding('C')" value="C" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="power('2')" value="X^2" >
            <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="returnResult()" value="=" >

        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code

```
form{
display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

```css
form{
display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design2.css" >
    <title>Calculator Italy</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="skyblue">
    <form>
        <div id="italyCalc">
            <input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('1')" value="1" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('2')" value="2" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('3')" value="3" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('+')" value="+" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('4')" value="4" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('5')" value="5" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('6')" value="6" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="deleteLast()" value="<--" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('7')" value="7" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('8')" value="8" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('9')" value="9" >

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('.')" value="." ><br>
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('0')" value="0" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('-')" value="-" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('*')" value="*" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('/')" value="/" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="adding('C')" value="C" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="power('2')" value="X^2" >
            <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="returnResult()" value="=" >

        </div>
        <div id="italyCalc2">
            <input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('1')" value="1" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('2')" value="2" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('3')" value="3" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('+')" value="+" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('4')" value="4" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('5')" value="5" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('6')" value="6" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="deleteLast()" value="<--" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('7')" value="7" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('8')" value="8" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('9')" value="9" >

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('.')" value="." ><br>
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('0')" value="0" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('-')" value="-" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('*')" value="*" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('/')" value="/" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="adding('C')" value="C" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="power('2')" value="X^2" >
            <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="returnResult()" value="=" >

        </div>
    </form>
<script src="logic2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to explain what you did there

Answer (score 1):

Wrap both the calculator `div` in one `div` with id `calculatorContainer`

```
#calculatorContainer{ display: flex;flex-direction:row}
```

Jsbin: 
http://jsbin.com/becumoxobi/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

try this jsfiddle I made:
https://jsfiddle.net/5se8p4t3/

I nested the calculators inside of a div with a class, in this case I called it `flexbox` and added the following css to it:

```
.flexbox {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

that's basically it.